# Publishing appointment change events from outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I am working on the project to import appointment items in outlook to different app. I am thinking of listening [item change event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-itemchange-event-outlook) for appointments then pushing the latest event by interval. For example, if a user is updating appointment 'A' then the plug-in will keep collecting the latest change. At certain point (say after 30 seconds), the plug-in publishes the event to target app via API. I am doing it by interval to reduce the amount of small changes to be published and also because of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654428/itemchangeevent-fired-multiple-times). Do you guys think this is the approach I can take? Can I use SignalR or stream processing here? There will be 1000 users to publish events. If you guys ever worked on similar project then please share. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to Event sourcing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to run a secondary thread in a VSTO based add-in where you can do all necessary web calls for uploading the latest changes from Outlook.

The [Thread.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method causes the operating system to change the state of the current instance to `ThreadState.Running`, and optionally supplies an object containing data to be used by the method the thread executes. Once a thread is in the `ThreadState.Running` state, the operating system can schedule it for execution. The thread begins executing at the first line of the method represented by the `ThreadStart` or `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate supplied to the thread constructor. Note that the call to Start does not block the calling thread. Finally, as you described, you may cache changes and upload the changes periodically by chunks of data.